# Get the following errors when I compile with G++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am a bit new to programming as you can probably tell from my prior question(s). I was wondering if anyone could help me with this recent problem I've had. I am trying to compile a script main.cpp using g++ but I get the following errors:

```
Donny@Donny-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/Donny/Desktop/equation/equations/equations
$ g++ main.cpp -o don.exe
main.cpp:3:11: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
 void main(){
       ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:36:22: error: ‘pow’ was not declared in this scope
  float n=pow(10.0,9.0);
                  ^
main.cpp:43:27: error: ‘sin’ was not declared in this scope
  float R56=(lb1/sin(theta1)) * ((tan(theta1))-theta1) + (lb2/sin(theta1)) *                ((tan(theta1))-theta1) +
                       ^
main.cpp:43:44: error: ‘tan’ was not declared in this scope
  float R56=(lb1/sin(theta1)) * ((tan(theta1))-theta1) + (lb2/sin(theta1)) *     ((tan(theta1))-theta1) +
                                        ^
main.cpp:48:40: error: ‘cos’ was not declared in this scope
  d*((pow(tan(theta1),2))/cos(theta1)) +
                                    ^
```

The weird thing is that this code works when compiled with microsoft visual studio 2010 C++. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

So, the  fixed a lot of the errors shown above, but I am still having a little difficulty fixing the void main error. Here is how my code looks:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
void main(){
    float r, i, f, beta, alpha;
    cout<<"Enter value of R : ";............
```

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first error's easy enough to handle; change your definition of `main` to be an `int` and return `0` upon successful completion. The other errors are likely due to your omission of `<cmath>` (which is where I believe those functions are defined).

Comment: The weird thing is that it compiled with microsoft visual studio 2010 C++.

Comment: I doubt it. The two compilers aren't so different as to allow a main method with a void signature.

Comment: @NWard, it's a non-standard extension supported by Microsoft. As long as your `main()` doesn't try to return anything it's allowed by the Microsoft C++ compiler.

Comment: Eugh, yikes. The more you know, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: You'd be surprised the amount of stupid crap MSVC allows you to get away with. I always run win-LLVM clang with `-Wall` in a separate terminal while coding using `gulp.watch` just to show compilation errors.

Comment: Your title is not descriptive at all.

Comment: @wolfPack88, `return 0;` is implicit for `main`.

Comment: `return EXIT_SUCCESS` or `return EXIT_FAILURE` are good practice even if `return 0` is implicit and Visual C++ allows a void return type.

Comment: @chris: I know, but I feel it's still good practice to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The first error should be self-explanatory. The standard says that the `main` function must return `int` but you have declared it as `void`. Return `0` from your `main` function to indicate normal termination. The Microsoft compiler is not as strict on this point.

All your remaining errors can be remedied by using `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: But since the code is C++ the `#include <cmath>` header is more appropriate.

Comment: You do not have to explicitly `return 0` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS` from your `main` function.

Comment: Hi, so this is the edit I made for the <cmath>, but I need help understanding what to do with the void main:

    #include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    using namespace std;
    void main(){
    float r, i, f, beta, alpha;
    cout<<"Enter value of R : ";

Comment: @user1886681 please stop calling this a "void main", this is an **int main**.